# Dotnet Odata client for an Olingo Odata V4 service

Tags: c#, .net, odata, olingo

I'm developing a Dotnet client application (CSharp) for an OData service. The OData service (V4) is implemented in Java with Apache 4.2.0 Olingo library.

On the client side, the proxy classes were created with "Connected OData Service".

I'm trying to get an whole EntitySet with the following code:

```
var ctx = new Container(new Uri(uriString: "http://localhost:8080/odata/PaisService.svc/"));

IEnumerable<Pais> paises = ctx.Paises.Execute();

foreach (Pais pais in paises)
{
     Console.WriteLine(pais.Descripcion);
}
```

When i execute the app i get the following exception:

```
Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233079

Message=Error al procesar esta solicitud.
Source=Microsoft.OData.Client
StackTrace:
en Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement]>(DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
       en Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
       en Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
       en System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       en System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       en TelerikWpfPoC_1.App..ctor() en c:\users\diego.cairone\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TelerikWpfPoC-1\TelerikWpfPoC-1\App.xaml.cs:línea 20
       en TelerikWpfPoC_1.App.Main() en c:\users\diego.cairone\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TelerikWpfPoC-1\TelerikWpfPoC-1\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:línea 0
       en System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       en System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       en Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=La carga de respuesta no es una carga de respuesta válida. Asegúrese de que el elemento de nivel superior sea un elemento Atom o JSON válido o pertenezca al espacio de nombres 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/data'.
       Source=Microsoft.OData.Client
       StackTrace:
            en Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateODataMessageReader(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, ODataPayloadKind& payloadKind)
            en Microsoft.OData.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateMaterializerForMessage(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, Type materializerType, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
            en Microsoft.OData.Client.MaterializeAtom..ctor(ResponseInfo responseInfo, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
            en Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.CreateMaterializer(ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
            en Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ProcessResult[TElement](ProjectionPlan plan)
            en Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
       InnerException:
```

I'm not understanding what is this error and how to fix it.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please the translate the spanish parts of the error into english?

Comment: As far as I understand the spanish parts, the response of the server is not valid OData and cannot be interpreted. Maybe you use [Wireshark](http://ttps://www.wireshark.org) to see, what the server responses.

Comment: The spanish parts say: The response payload is a not a valid response payload
Please make sure that the top level element is a valid Atom or JSON element

Comment: Did you try to trace the response with wireshark?

Comment: Thanks @scher for your interest but i decided to change the framework from Olingo to SDL that seem to work for me.